# combining rows with dplyr when number of columns is unknown

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr

I have a tibble with several columns, including an ID column and a "score" column. The ID column has some duplicated values. I want to create a tibble that has one row per unique ID, and the same number of columns as the original tibble. For any ID, the "score" value in this new tibble should be the mean of the scores for the ID in the original tibble. And for any ID, the value for the other columns should be the first value that appears for that ID in the original tibble.

When the number of columns in the original tibble is small and known, this is an easy problem. Example:

```
scores <- tibble(
  ID    = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
  score = 1:5, 
  a     = 6:10)
scores %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(score = mean(score), a = first(a))
```

But I often work with tibbles (or data frames) that have dozens of columns. I don't know in advance how many columns there will be or how they will be named. In these cases, I still want a function that takes, within each group, the mean of the `score` column and the first value of the other columns. But it isn't practical to spell out the name of each column. Is there a generic command that will let me `summarize()` by taking the mean of one column and the first value of all of the others?

A two-step solution would start by using `mutate()` to replace each score within a group with the mean of those scores. Then I could create my desired tibble by taking the first row of each group. But is there a one-step solution, perhaps using one of the select_helpers in dplyr?

[Summarizing unknown number of column in R using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722829/summarizing-unknown-number-of-column-in-r-using-dplyr) is the closest post that I've been able to find. But I can't see that it quite speaks to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mutate` to get the mean values and then use `slice` to get the first row of each group, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

scores %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(score = mean(score)) %>% 
  slice(1L)

#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: ID [3]

#     ID score     a
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1   1.5     6
#2     2   3.5     8
#3     3   5.0    10
```